# Latitude and Longitude are set to 0 first time I open the App IOS

Tags: xcode, cllocationmanager

In my main ViewController I ask for the user position with the following code:

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

}
```

The first time the app gets opened it asks for the user location and I get latitude 0 and longitude 0, if I open the app again (since the user already accepted to share his location) I get the correct latitude and longitude, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't you need to ask the user for permission in order to track their location?

Comment: It ask only the first time I start the App then it doesn't ask anymore (at least on IOS7 it works like this).

Comment: @Signo - In case If you are trying in simulator by default it might taking location none so u might getting location 0. Check Simulator -> Debug -> locations